# Why do I get JWTStrategy requires a secret or key with NestJS?

Tags: authentication, passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

I'm implementing authentication for my NestJS project. I strictly followed the NestJS documentation and [this](https://codebrains.io/nest-js-express-jwt-authentication-with-typeorm-and-passport/) but I still get an error when I try to start the API. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this. I tried setting the `secretOrKey` to hardcoded string but no to effect then I moved it to a `.env` still not working.

Below are my code for the module and the JwtStrategy file.

```
// AuthModule
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    UserModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Registration]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secretOrPrivateKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES }
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```
// JWTStrategy
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from "passport-jwt";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      passReqToCallback: true,
      secretOrKey: 'test'
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: any, done: Function) {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUserToken(payload)
    if (!user) {
      return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false)
    }

    done(null, user)
  }
}
```

This is the error I get from the terminal

```
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +76ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +121ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 6876   - 05/11/2020, 10:54:31 PM   [ExceptionHandler] JwtStrategy requires a secret or key +20ms
TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key
    at new JwtStrategy (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:45:15)
    at new MixinStrategy (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/passport/passport.strategy.js:31:13)
    at new LocalStrategy (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/dist/src/auth/local.strategy.js:18:9)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:289:19)
    at callback (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:76:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:117:24)
    at async Injector.loadInstance (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:80:9)
    at async Injector.loadProvider (/Users/user/Documents/code/sideline/hyperspotters-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:37:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
✨  Done in 11.99s.
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem, on my local.strategy.ts file instead of importing Strategy class from passport-local it imported from passport-jwt.